# How would I create dynamic tasks/threads to trigger the same function/method in which the tasks/threads are controlled from a Database?

Tags: c#, .net, task

I build a service that would call tasks to be performed.  This is table driven and dynamic.  So at each tick of the service (every 10 seconds) it would call the SQL table and find out what is active.  If it is active, it will build a new task and put it into an object list.  Each task calls the same function but I pass through a unique datarow (which contains a unique ID from the datatable) into the passing parameters for the method.

When the tasks run at the same time, I receive random errors (from the database calls) that have no relation to the task that is supposed to be running.

So the question is, is it possible that the tasks that run the same method/function at the same time will step on each other and causing the threads to intersect?

Here is my code:

```
namespace ReportService
{
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    //public timer
    private static System.Timers.Timer timerReports = null;

    //collection of tasks
    //private static BlockingCollection<ReportTasks> tasksCollection = new BlockingCollection<ReportTasks>();
    private static List<ReportTasks> tasksCollection = new List<ReportTasks>();

    #region Service functions

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ExceptionInfo exceptioninfo = new ExceptionInfo();
            exceptioninfo.LogType = "L";
            exceptioninfo.ClassName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString();
            exceptioninfo.MethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            exceptioninfo.OptionalMessage = "Service On";

            Log.WriteToLog(exceptioninfo, ConfigSettings.GetServiceSettings());

            timerReports = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timerReports.Interval = 30000;  //30 secconds
            timerReports.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timerReports_Tick);
            timerReports.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Get Service settings
            dynamic ServiceSettings = ConfigSettings.GetServiceSettings();

            if (ex.Data["WrittenToLog"] == null)
            {
                //set new object
                ex.Data.Add("WrittenToLog", true);

                //build exception object
                ExceptionInfo exceptioninfo = new ExceptionInfo();
                exceptioninfo.LogType = "E";
                exceptioninfo.ClassName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString();
                exceptioninfo.MethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
                exceptioninfo.InnerException = ex;

                //write to log
                Log.WriteToLog(exceptioninfo, ServiceSettings);
            }
            else if ((bool)ex.Data["WrittenToLog"] == false)
            {
                //set written to log as true
                ex.Data["WrittenToLog"] = true;

                //build exception object
                ExceptionInfo exceptioninfo = new ExceptionInfo();
                exceptioninfo.LogType = "E";
                exceptioninfo.ClassName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString();
                exceptioninfo.MethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
                exceptioninfo.InnerException = ex;

                //write to log
                Log.WriteToLog(exceptioninfo, ServiceSettings);
            }

            //throw exception to back out of process
            //throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {

            timerReports.Enabled = false;

            ExceptionInfo exceptioninfo = new ExceptionInfo();
            exceptioninfo.LogType = "L";
            exceptioninfo.ClassName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString();
            exceptioninfo.MethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            exceptioninfo.OptionalMessage = "Service Off";

            Log.WriteToLog(exceptioninfo, ConfigSettings.GetServiceSettings());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Get Service settings
            dynamic ServiceSettings = ConfigSettings.GetServiceSettings();

            if (ex.Data["WrittenToLog"] == null)
            {
                //set new object
                ex.Data.Add("WrittenToLog", true);

                //build exception object
                ExceptionInfo exceptioninfo = new ExceptionInfo();
                exceptioninfo.LogType = "E";
                exceptioninfo.ClassName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString();
                exceptioninfo.MethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
                exceptioninfo.InnerException = ex;

                //write to log
                Log.WriteToLog(exceptioninfo, ServiceSettings);
            }
            else if ((bool)ex.Data["WrittenToLog"] == false)
            {
                //set written to log as true
                ex.Data["WrittenToLog"] = true;

                //build exception object
                ExceptionInfo exceptioninfo = new ExceptionInfo();
                exceptioninfo.LogType = "E";
                exceptioninfo.ClassName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString();
                exceptioninfo.MethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
                exceptioninfo.InnerException = ex;

                //write to log
                Log.WriteToLog(exceptioninfo, ServiceSettings);
            }

            //throw exception to back out of process
            //throw ex;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void timerReports_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //check to see if task is running, if not, process EDI
        try
        {
            //remove completed tasks               
            tasksCollection.RemoveAll(item => item.ReportTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);


            //Get Service settings
            dynamic ServiceSettings = ConfigSettings.GetServiceSettings();

            //set the SQL command and parameters
            SQLcommand Sqlcommandobj = new SQLcommand();
            Sqlcommandobj.SQLcmd = @"SELECT *,'TABLE' AS [TABLE_NAME] 
                                     FROM EX_TABLE";
            Sqlcommandobj.SQLcmdType = CommandType.Text;

            //fill in list 
            DataSet dsReportSchedules = Queries.ServiceSQLExecute(ServiceSettings, Sqlcommandobj);

            //loop through each schedule to add/remove tasks
            foreach (DataRow drReport in dsReportSchedules.Tables["SCHEDULES"].Rows)
            {
                if (!tasksCollection.Any(item => item.ReportID == Helper.GetValueFromDataRowInt32(drReport, "REPORTS_SCHEDULE_ID")))
                {
                    if (Helper.GetValueFromDataRowString(drReport, "ACTIVE") == "1" && Helper.GetValueFromDataRowString(drReport, "DELETE_DATE") == string.Empty)
                    {
                        //create cancellation for task
                        var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                        //create new task
                        Task newTask = new Task(() => ReportProcess.BeginProcessingReport(drReport, ServiceSettings), ts.Token);

                        //fill in report tasks object
                        ReportTasks ReportTasks = new ReportTasks();
                        ReportTasks.ReportID = Helper.GetValueFromDataRowInt32(drReport, "REPORTS_SCHEDULE_ID");
                        ReportTasks.ReportName = Helper.GetValueFromDataRowString(drReport, "NAME");
                        ReportTasks.ReportTask = newTask;
                        ReportTasks.TaskID = newTask.Id;
                        ReportTasks.Active = Convert.ToBoolean(drReport["ACTIVE"]);
                        ReportTasks.CancelTokenSource = ts;

                        //add to task collection
                        tasksCollection.Add(ReportTasks);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //remove if not active or deleted
                    if (Helper.GetValueFromDataRowString(drReport, "ACTIVE") != "1" || Helper.GetValueFromDataRowString(drReport, "DELETE_DATE") != string.Empty)
                    {
                        var itemToRemove = tasksCollection.SingleOrDefault(item => item.ReportID == Helper.GetValueFromDataRowInt32(drReport, "REPORTS_SCHEDULE_ID"));
                        if (itemToRemove.ReportID > 0)
                        {
                            //check to see if task is running
                            if (itemToRemove.ReportTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
                            {
                                itemToRemove.CancelTokenSource.Cancel();
                            }

                            //remove task from collection
                            tasksCollection.Remove(itemToRemove);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //trigger each task
            foreach (var str in tasksCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task: " + str.ReportName + " - Status: " + str.ReportTask.Status);
                if (str.ReportTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion | str.ReportTask.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
                {
                    str.ReportTask.Start();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Get Service settings
            dynamic ServiceSettings = ConfigSettings.GetServiceSettings();

            if (ex.Data["WrittenToLog"] == null)
            {
                //set new object
                ex.Data.Add("WrittenToLog", true);

                //build exception object
                ExceptionInfo exceptioninfo = new ExceptionInfo();
                exceptioninfo.LogType = "E";
                exceptioninfo.ClassName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString();
                exceptioninfo.MethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
                exceptioninfo.InnerException = ex;

                //write to log
                Log.WriteToLog(exceptioninfo, ServiceSettings);
            }
            else if ((bool)ex.Data["WrittenToLog"] == false)
            {
                //set written to log as true
                ex.Data["WrittenToLog"] = true;

                //build exception object
                ExceptionInfo exceptioninfo = new ExceptionInfo();
                exceptioninfo.LogType = "E";
                exceptioninfo.ClassName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString();
                exceptioninfo.MethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
                exceptioninfo.InnerException = ex;

                //write to log
                Log.WriteToLog(exceptioninfo, ServiceSettings);
            }

            //throw exception to back out of process
            //throw ex;
        }

    }

}
}
```

In the above, during the timer tick, I go through each record in the task list and delete out the completed tasks.  Then I grab the records from the DB and determine if they need to be added.  It will also check to see if a user marked them for deleted or inactive and it will use a cancellation token to stop it and then remove it from the list.  Last, it will loop through and trigger the tasks in the list.

This is the process that gets called on each task:

```
public static void BeginProcessingReport(Object drReportSchedule, dynamic 
ServiceSettings)
{
}
```

and here is the object that contains the tasks for the List<>

```
public struct ReportTasks
{
    public string ReportName;
    public Int32 ReportID;
    public int TaskID;
    public Task ReportTask;
    public bool Active;
    public CancellationTokenSource CancelTokenSource;
    public ReportTasks(string name, Int32 reportID, int id, Task task, DataRow drReport, bool active, CancellationTokenSource canceltokensource, CancellationToken canceltoken)
    {
        ReportName = name;
        ReportID = reportID;
        TaskID = id;
        ReportTask = task;
        Active = active;
        CancelTokenSource = canceltokensource;
    }
}
```

Hopefully that is enough information and any help will be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE:**  I was able to resolve the issues by creating a thread for the main processing of the tasks.  Moved the functionality out of the tick method and put it in its own method to be called by the thread.

So every tick from the timer will check the thread to see if its running or not.

```
private static Thread mainThread = null;  

    private void timerReports_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //create thread if null
        if (mainThread == null)
        {
            mainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Process));
        }

        //start thread if stopped or unstarted, else, it is still running and do nothing
        if(mainThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped || mainThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted)
        {
            mainThread.Start();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

The above code didnt work as I still had issues with tasks retriggering when they werent completed.

So let me reword my question:
How would I create dynamic tasks/threads to trigger the same function/method in which the tasks/threads are controlled from a Database?  It would need the ability to remove threads and tasks if the records are deleted or set to Active = 0 which is a bit field in SQL to determine if the record should trigger or not.

Comment: `I receive random errors (from the database calls)` What are these errors?

Comment: Depends on how you started those tasks, and what you mean by "step on each other".

Comment: @mjwills I could post the errors, but no one would understand what they mean.  Basically, it will say my select statement is incorrect, but it's calling the wrong select statement.  Also, I have a process that queries either Oracle or MS SQL, and its calling MS SQL when it is an oracle process.  Which leads me to think it's the settings are overlapping somehow.

Comment: Ultimately, we can't help you without a [mcve]. The issue is likely in some form of reuse of SQL objects (possibly in `ServiceSQLExecute`). But we can't know for sure without a [mcve]. _You'll know you have a [mcve] when we can copy and paste the code you provide in the question into a console app and it compiles successfully._

Comment: Ok:  Message --- {0}Incorrect syntax near 'CUBE'.  This error occurred in my MS SQL process instead of the Oracle process which is leading me to believe that information is being shared across the threads.

Comment: I think everyone is missing the point to my question.  I am curious to see if multiple tasks are triggered at once, would they share information between the threads or will they be separate.  When I test one at a time, I receive no issues or errors.  But when they trigger at the same time, that's when the above issue occurs which makes no sense since its the same select statement.

Comment: `would they share information between the threads or will they be separate.` The answer is - "it depends". Can they share stuff? Yes. It all depends on how thread-safe the rest of your code (which we can't see) is. Given it is failing, I think it is safe to assume the code isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By "step on each other" do you mean that the tick event occurs again whilst the previous event is still being processed?

In which case just disable the timer in the beginning of the tick event and re-enable when processing is complete

Comment: Ah, I think you hit the nail on the head with this one. I remember doing threading at my last job and I think this was our resolve.

Comment: What I ultimatly did was create a single thread for the process to run.  This run contains the dynamic tasks that are called but within this thread.  When the timer ticks, it will check to see if the thread is running.  If it is, then just skip over running the process this task.